# x-ref the python standard library with intersphinx while omitting the module name

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, cross-reference

**EDIT:** Other answers than the one I provided are welcome!

Consider the following function:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union


def func(path: Union[str, Path]) -> None:
    """My super function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    path : str | Path
        path to a super file.
    """
    pass
```

When documenting with sphinx, I would like to cross-ref both `str` and `Path` with intersphinx. But obviously, it does not work for the latter since it is referenced as `pathlib.Path` in the `objects.inv` file.

Is there a way to tell intersphinx/sphinx that `Path` is from the `pathlib` module? Without resorting to:

```
path : str | `pathlib.Path`
```

or

```
path : str | `~pathlib.Path`
```

which does not render nicely in a python interpreter, e.g. IPython.

Comment: Why the backticks? Doesn't `path : str | pathlib.Path` work (even if it may not be exactly what you want)?

Comment: Hmm, true the backticks are probably not required. But it's still not what I would ideally like.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Without resorting to...". With backticks, no clickable link is created.

Comment: @mzjn In the above example, str will be automatically linked to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str I would like Path to link to the documentation for pathlib.Path without having to explicitly tell in the docstring that a Path is part of the pathlib module. Instead, I would prefer a configuration variable which let's me tell to sphinx where it should look for Path.

Comment: Forget about the backticks.. I want to keep `str | Path`. Without backticks. That was just to illustrate what I would like to *avoid* (haven't tested if the backticks were necessary or not to get the x-ref, and they are probably not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpydoc` can do this through `x-ref` aliases: https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In the configuration `conf.py`:

```
numpydoc_xref_param_type = True
numpydoc_xref_aliases = {
    "Path": "pathlib.Path",
}
```

It might try to match other words from the parameters types of the Parameters, Other Parameters, Returns and Yields sections. They can be ignored by adding the following to the configuration `conf.py`:

```
numpydoc_xref_ignore = {
    "of",
    "shape",
}
```

`numpydoc` also offers other useful tools, such as docsting validation, which can be configured in `conf.py` with the keys described here: https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#configuration

Comment: Technically all `nunmpydoc_xref_aliases` does is create a dictionary of `{"Path":"pathlib.Path"}`. Is there a difference between a normal dictionary and this?

Comment: Agree, but what it also does is render the documentation correctly. A regular dictionary defined in `conf.py`without numpydoc installed will not do anything? While with numpydoc the documentation is rendered with both `path : str | Path` linked to their respective documentation.